# Database Design for monitoring patients

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to ask for your help, as I am stuck in a project I am working on for monitoring patients from their homes.

I am a PHP/MySQL developer, and if you could guide me in a right direction, it would be great.
Here is what I want:

I have 3 type of users: Admin, Patients, Doctors

1. Each user must login to use the system. So we have login information.
2. A doctor can have under his/her responsibility many patients. Thus, he is connected to many patients. (Will check their daily measurements)
3. A patient can be under responsibility of only one doctor.
4. I also want to hold personal data of patients and doctors, apart from their login details. (So I can make profiles for them, but they will have different information)
5. Will also have an internal messaging system so that logged in users can communicate.
6. Specific(about 3-4) measurements will be stored for each patient every day. (Patients will enter those using a form)
7. The last thing is that i want a mailing list for the patients, in order to send them if they want daily reminder emails to upload their measurements.

Please, what kind of database design do I need. How can I arrange tables and ids and stuff.
If you could help me, that would be great!

Thanks in advance. 
Regards, 
Andrew.

Comment: Has somebody hired you to author this software?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd have much confidence in this system if I were a patient.  Would you want your family members to depend on it?

Comment: @JaredFarrish No, I had a simpler project as part of a course, and I am trying to make it more complex now.

Comment: If you are in the United Staes, suggest you first read up on HIPAA. If you design a studnt project considering the requirements of HIPAA in mind, then you will be far in advance of the other graduates when it comes time to get a job especially in this field.

Comment: I never said it wasn't a school project.  I'm asking....

Comment: @TimoWillemsen - The responses to the question actually could depend on know which it is; a real live system of this kind would require considerable effort to protect PII and follow HIPAA requirements. An exercise would obviously probably de-emphasize those elements.

Comment: @AndI2eaS - I would suggest possibly looking into [doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) within [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) or some combination like that. The scope of the question(s) you've asked here are well beyond a simple enough answer for SO.

Comment: Guys, one click into his profile: 22yrs, Greece -- he's not going to program the new system for some US hospital so stop giving him HIPAA-flak and start to answer his actual question.

Comment: @JaredFarrish while you are correct about that. You know yourself that's not what you and duffymo meant by asking those questions.

Comment: @TimoWillemsen - There probably was a bit of being taken aback when I first read the question. It really probably belonged on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead of SO, though, at least in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already identified a number of tables and their cardinalities.

You might have a User table and different roles: Doctor, Patient, Admin, etc.

Users have credentials; that's 1:1.

Profile will have Address, ContactInfo, etc.

The measurements piece is getting tricky.  I'd recommend having a look at Martin Fowler's [Analysis Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201895420).  He has a nice chapter modeling the situation you're talking about here.  It's subtle.